# Double integral uv-sub

Tags: integration

$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2-2x}\frac{\left(2x-y\right)^{2}}{2x+y}dydx$

I set $u=2x-y$, and $v=2x+y$, and I found the Jacobian to be $\frac{1}{4}$. I have found that $x=\frac{u+v}{4}, y=\frac{-u+v}{2}$. But I do not know how to proceed from here. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

All you did was fine, and now oberve that

$$0\le x=\frac{u+v}4\le1\iff0\le u+v\le4$$

and also

$$0\le y=\frac{-u+v}2\le2-\frac{u+v}2\iff\frac{u+v}2\le v\le2$$

Well, now you can calculate the new limits ofr $\;u,\,v\;$ ...

Comment: sorry, but could you explain what to do next? I'm still confused from what you do from here since you would need to separate u and v

Comment: For eample, from the first line you already have that $\;0\le u+v\;$ , so from the second line we already know that $\;0\le\frac{u+v}2\le v\le 2\implies 0\le v\le 2\;$ , and there you have limits for $\;v\;$ . Now try with $\;u\;$ ...This is already a regular, usual exercise in double integration!

Answer (score 0):

It is actually easier just to integrate directly as follows,

$$\begin{align}
&\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2-2x}\frac{\left(2x-y\right)^{2}}{2x+y}dydx \\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2-2x} \left( y-6x+\frac{16x^2}{2x+y}\right) dydx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac12 y-6xy+{16x^2}\ln(2x+y)\right)\bigg|_0^{2-2x}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{1}\left(2(1-x)^2-12x(1-x)-{16x^2}\ln x\right)dx\\
&=\frac49
\end{align}$$